# jQuery add data to class

Tags: jquery, syntax

Can someone help me with this syntax please:

```
jQuery(".listid' + data[i].id + '").hover(function(){
    $(".list' + data[i].id + '").stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
});
```

End result should be: show `.list1` if you rollover `.listid1`, show `.list2` if you rollover `.listid2`, etc.

Comment: you never actually close your quotes. `$('.listid' + data[i].id)` is probably what you're going for.

Comment: I think the quotes are wrong - try this jQuery(".listid" + data[i].id)

Comment: What is your HTML? You could possibly make this work via DOM traversal instead of selecting by an indexed class.

Comment: I guess it's more than a syntax problem. I've uploaded the files so you can see what I'm trying to accomplish: [link](http://moresidencesatlanta.com/map/map.html)

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as shown below

```
jQuery(".listid" + data[i].id).hover(
            function(){
            $(".list" + data[i].id ).stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up quotes:

```
jQuery(".listid' + data[i].id + '").hover(
        function(){
        $(".list' + data[i].id + '").stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
        }
    );
```

You also need to store `data[i].id` in a closure:

```
(function(id){
    jQuery(".listid" + id).hover(
            function(){
            $(".list" + id).stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
            }
        );
})(data[i].id)
```

Otherwise, the callback won't work, as `i` will have changed.